# rosbridge on fuerte closes immediately

Tags: ros-fuerte, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm having a problem where rosbridge.py closes websocket connections immediately on Fuerte.  This may be related to changes in the timing functions.  Originally ROSProxy.py used roslib.rostime, which no longer seems to exist on Fuerte.  Perhaps the rospy.rostime behavior is not the same in some important way?  The related compile question is available here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/33825/rosbridge-error-in-rosproxypy-on-fuerte-with

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33835/rosbridge-on-fuerte-closes-immediately/) by [Dave](https://answers.ros.org/users/1147/dave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/33825/rosbridge-error-in-rosproxypy-on-fuerte-with?answer=34112#post-id-34112) answer.

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1